How can I convert the array of values to Text format in AWS glue on Notebook?
Hi all I am a bit new to AWS Glue and would like to ask the following. I have a set of data (TableName: "Flights") from AWS Glue with schema as follows. I used dynamic frame to create the content.
Schema
[Table](https://i.sstatic.net/oTBHcTTA.png)[1]
I have been working on notebook to extract the number, and I have checked on the exported CSV that Column "PathNo" has values. In between, there is a designated crawler to crawl the data from CSV, and thus a table is created.
But after I have queried the table on AWS Athena, the PathNo becomes null. Any chance I can export the PathNo as Text"(?! - as i know string is the only substitute) in Athena? Many thanks for the help in advance.
I am looking for a series of codes, or possibly another solutions can help with extracting the column's value. Many thanks

As per the Schema, PathNo is a string, but the table shows that it in a list format. Have you tried to make sure it stays a string? Try applymapping to the dynamic frame and make sure it is a string. On a side note, add your current results and expected results too as there might be better ways to achieve it. difficult to understand why you want a list as a string

Hi Pushkar thanks for the advice. I have tried printSchema() and it shows that the PathNo is a  "string". I have applied "applymapping" by DF in notebook as suggested but still in vain -- the CSV file that I have exported from Data Catalog to S3 bucket shows the data(like '[1, 2, 3]')), but when queried in AWS Athena it is a column with null values.
Ultimately I want the PathNo to be "string" value instead of null in Athena for building the data pipeline. Thanks in advance.
